# Sub sites inherit parent theme

Tags: development, branding

I am trying to get subsites of my parent site to inherit the same masterpage as their parent. I have a feature stapled to all the default site templates that contain my master page.

I have created a Event Receiver called ChildSiteInit. It has the following code:

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint;

namespace SP_Intranet.ChildSiteInit
{
    public class ChildSiteInit : SPWebEventReceiver
    {
        public override void WebProvisioned(SPWebEventProperties properties)
        {
            SPWeb childSite = properties.Web;
            SPWeb topSite = childSite.Site.RootWeb;
            childSite.MasterUrl = topSite.MasterUrl;
            childSite.CustomMasterUrl = topSite.CustomMasterUrl;
            childSite.AlternateCssUrl = topSite.AlternateCssUrl;
            childSite.SiteLogoUrl = topSite.SiteLogoUrl;
            childSite.Update();
        }
    }
}
```

This is taken from [Inside Microsoft SharePoint 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff742318.aspx) (direct copy bar the namespace).

It is displayed in my feature and the feature is deployed. The feature is deployed at site collection level.

When I create a new sub site the parent masterpage is not inherited.

*Updated code removing usings*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this in a sandboxed solution?

Is this in a Publishing Site?

Also, remove the unneeded usings (right click the code, Organise Usings) - Security, Utilities, Workflow. Keeps the code cleaner a bit.

The code itself looks fine, try putting a breakpoint on the first line and debug, see if it bails out at any point and gives you clues as to why (I currently have a problem trying to set the Navigation settings of a Publishing site using the exact same event receiver, and it's bailing out, as I think the sandboxed environment can't handle it. I had to debug to reveal this).

Comment: Not sandboxed. I get this on all site types. Thanks for the tips about using I will remove them. I will try some debugging and see what I can come up with.

Comment: The code is not being hit by the debugger. Not sure why but that would be why it is not being applied.

Comment: I had a rogue feature causing it to fail. Deleting the feature fixed the problem.